# Clicking on 'tag a badge to track' gear icon also opens a 'pop-up message' box

Tags: bug, badges, design

I just noticed the new functionality i.e. "Choose between tracking your next-privilege and a tag badge" added to 'REPUTATION' box. It's a great improvement to a user profile.

Upon toying with this feature I noticed that clicking on a 'tag a badge to track' *gear* icon also opens a 'pop-up message' box for the corresponding tag badge.

Here is a screenshot for the same along with steps to reproduce indicated with number. Please note, after clicking the gear icon a small 'pop-up message box' is immediately loaded and placed behind the '**Select your next badge**' big pop-up overlay. Closing this large overlay reveals the small 'pop-up message box'.

> [image]

If you select a 'new tag badge' to track (from the large overlay box) then this small 'pop-up message box is removed. But, if you don't select a new tag badge to track then the pop-up message box stays in place i.e. kinda informing you about your currently set tag badge. Also, one can always obtain the tag badge info. by clicking on the tag itself e.g. 'discussion' (in my case).

Is this suppose to behave this way? I'm curious to know as I could not find any information about this feature release.

Comment: I would tag this with [tag:bug] instead of [tag:discussion].