# Can't easily dismiss the tag/privilege tracking popup

Tags: bug, profile-page, badge-progress

If you click on the cog to bring up the tag/privilege selection popup, neither clicking on the Esc key, nor mouse clicking outside the popup dismisses it.

You need less than 20K for this.

Comment: +1 I agree... I noticed that when I posted my [other question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264610/clicking-on-tag-a-badge-to-track-gear-icon-also-opens-a-pop-up-message-box). Also, where is this 20K comes from, we both are below 20K and we can track tag a badge / next-privilege

Comment: If you've more than 20K you can't track progress (only badges) so the popup does not appear for you.

Comment: Thanks for that note. I thought it was other way round ... 20K or less can't track progress... It's still confusing for me as more reps. should have more privileges

Comment: If you've more than 20K there are "no more worlds to conquer". The popup is not displayed, you can only track badges.

Comment: did you read [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258350/254554)?

Comment: Of course, that's how I knew this feature existed.